# AngularJS Smart-Table Client Side Pagination - What is the minimum version of AngularJS required?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, client-side, smart-table

I am developing a webpage that displays data in a smart table because I will need to allow the user to select multiple rows for processing.

I am using `AngularJS` version 1.3.20.

I have a test web page upon which I copied the example found on GitHub (lorenzofox2.github.io/smart-table-website).  I copied the provided table script into my test `HTML`.  I copied the provided `JavaScript` script into my client controller.  I execute the web page through my application.  The webpage opens with the appropriate data displayed.  The webpage does not display the pagination in the footer as defined.  I do not know why the pagination does not show.

Listed below, you will find `HTML`, `JavaScript`, and Results

**HTML :**

```
<div class="smart-table">
<table st-table="rowCollection" class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th st-sort="firstName">first name</th>
  <th st-sort="lastName">last name</th>
  <th st-sort="birthDate">birth date</th>
  <th st-sort="balance">balance</th>
  <th>email</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>
    <input st-search="'firstName'" placeholder="search for firstname" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
  </th>
  <th colspan="4">
    <input st-search placeholder="global search" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
  </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
  <td>{{row.firstName | uppercase}}</td>
  <td>{{row.lastName}}</td>
  <td>{{row.birthDate | date}}</td>
  <td>{{row.balance | currency}}</td>
  <td><a ng-href="mailto:{{row.email}}">email</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5" class="text-center">
      <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="itemsByPage" st-displayed-pages="7"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
</div>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
var
    nameList = ['Pierre', 'Pol', 'Jacques', 'Robert', 'Elisa'],
    familyName = ['Dupont', 'Germain', 'Delcourt', 'bjip', 'Menez'];

function createRandomItem() {
    var
        firstName = nameList[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)],
        lastName = familyName[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)],
        age = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
        email = firstName + lastName + '@whatever.com',
        balance = Math.random() * 3000;

    return{
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        age: age,
        email: email,
        balance: balance
    };
}

$scope.itemsByPage=15;

$scope.rowCollection = [];
for (var j = 0; j < 200; j++) {
    $scope.rowCollection.push(createRandomItem());
}
```

Results

[image]

I hope someone can let me know if I am using the appropriate version of `AngularJS`.  If so, I hope someone can guide me into what I missed?

Answer (score 0):

After further searching, this issue was the result of running version 1.3.0 of smart-table instead of 2.1.8.  After upgrading angular-smart-table to version 2.1.8, the issue was resolved